# Multiple development builds exported - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I just exported development build for my project. After seeing export data, I feel strange!!!

Multiple files get exported, so which one I require to install on my iPhone. Please check image given below for my point clear explanation:

[image]

I have exported build for all compatible device variants like this way:

[image]

Now I become confused which file I require to use for testing? Also which file I require sending to my customer.

As per my past build export experience, I was getting only one file to install on any device but this time running something different so please give some details about this.

Comment: It is because of app thining... Based on which device you are using, you need to install that binary...

Comment: For general, I have used bookapp.ipa from above but it didn't worked on my iPhone. What to do if I have iPhone8 plus?